# Get File Mimetype

Tags: java, spring-boot, mime-types

I am using springboot to upload file.

How to detect actual file mimetype after changing file extension?

Ex. if someone change abc.exe to abc.pdf then upload.

In that case I want to get actual extesion/mimetype that is .exe so I can restrict.

```
    public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println(file.getContentType());
    }
```

Above code returning application/pdf if I change abc.exe to abc.pdf where actual file is .exe

Comment: You could try using file signatures/magic numbers or just get the type before renaming the file.

Comment: If you have a file directly, there are [different ways](https://www.baeldung.com/java-file-mime-type) to determine the type. If you have a multipart file, you can use the method [MultipartFile.getContentType](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getContentType--) directly. There exists also a [nice tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) from Spring how to upload a file.

Comment: Please check updated code.